# Basic authorization in WEB API C# using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, asp.net-authorization

I have looked up all the questions regarding basic authorization in web api using httpweb request and none of them solved my problem. I have a web api (written in C#) and I want to establish basic authorization for the api. I also have a web page that I am using to call the api. However, it keeps returning "(401)Unauthorized" and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Right now I'm using the username and password in the code but I want there to be a pop up asking for credentials.

This is the code for my web page, calling the api:

```
string url = String.Format("http://example.com");
HttpWebRequest requestObj = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
requestObj.Method = "Get";
requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testing", "123456");

HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
string strresult = null;
using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

In my api, I opened a class called BasicAuthenticationAttribute and wrote this:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public static bool IsAuthorizedUser(string Username, string Password)
    {
        return Username == "testing" && Password == "123456";
    }
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
        {
            var authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            var decodeauthToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));
            var arrUserNameandPassword = decodeauthToken.Split(':');
            if (IsAuthorizedUser(arrUserNameandPassword[0], arrUserNameandPassword[1]))
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(arrUserNameandPassword[0]), null);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I have this:

```
 [BasicAuthentication]
 public class EventsController : ApiController
 {
 }
```

This is the error I'm receiving:
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: Have you inspected `decodeauthToken` with a debugger?

Comment: Don't you need to Replace "Basic" with a String.Empty? I always thought Basic Authentication came back with Basic in the name.  Need to find the example I copied before.

Comment: @JohnPete22 my thought exactly - just wanted OP to figure it out using a debugger :) Assuming it reaches that point at all.

Comment: @fredrik I haven't, how do I do that?

Comment: @JohnPete22 Not quite sure what to replace, where in the code do you think is the problem?

Comment: authToken.Replace("Basic", string.Empty)

Comment: Here is an example of an Auth Header: ```Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==```

Comment: @JohnPete22 where should I place that?

Comment: How you do that would depend heavily on which IDE you're using. There's usually a debug option in some menu.

Comment: I'd make authToken a string, and then once you have it then do a Replace on it.  But honestly it'd help you to DEBUG and see what authToken and decodeauthToken are, with and without the Replace.

Comment: @JohnPete22 how do I debug the api using credentials? because when I run it, it doesn't ask for username + password and just gives this message: This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 401

Comment: Do you have PostMan? Thats how I debug API calls.  Make the API call via PostMan to the localhost address, and when you're running in Debug mode that page will get hit that you requested via PostMan.

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: @JohnPete22 okay I dowloaded getpostman.com and ran the api with the username and password "testing" & "123456" and it worked. That means the problem is with the web page calling the api right? How do I fix it?

Comment: This goes more into the environment you're in and potential IIS stuff, and that is out of my realm.  You might have to search SO for this same issue, or raise a new question.  It might be as easy as making some Web.config changes, but I honestly don't know.  The link I posted in my Answer has a tidbit about adding to your webconfig for HttpModules.

Comment: But if my answer did help in the basic authentication part, feel free to mark it up :)  I will see if I can come across any info about allowing API calls and whats needed though.

Comment: Also, I think you're testing is why you're getting the issue. You're trying to make an API call to the same website you're own, and this might be why you're having issues.  But if you can successfully test on PostMan, then I think you're good to go.

Comment: @JohnPete22 Thank you so much! I'll keep searching

Answer (score 0):

Try adding credentials to credential cache with type of authorization and instead of using credentials directly use cache.

```
    string url = String.Format("http://example.com");
    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("testing", "123456"));
    HttpWebRequest requestObj = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    requestObj.PreAuthenticate = true;
    requestObj.Method = "Get";
    requestObj.Credentials = **credentialCache**;
    HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
    responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
    string strresult = null;
    using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I just tried what you wrote, still giving me the same message... Is there a way to have a popup asking for credentials?

Comment: Pop up is available only with Windows authorization and inside domain.

Comment: In general to solve it. Can you investigate what value is in `actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization`?

Comment: Okay. In my code is missing `requestObj.PreAuthenticate = true;`

Comment: tried adding requestObj.PreAuthenticate = true; and it didn't change anything

Comment: and what is in the authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the messages above, I believe the issue is because you are not removing "Basic" from the authentication header.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

What I'd do...

```
string authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
authToken = authToken.Replace("Basic", string.Empty);
var decodeauthToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));
```

And try this when you split. About the only thing different in your implementation than what I've done multiple times.

```
var arrUserNameandPassword = decodeauthToken.Split(':'c);
```

Comment: I added that but it's still giving me the same message. I know for sure that the api itself works because everything was fine before I tried adding authentication.

Comment: Are there permission issues with the file / folder you are trying to access? And please, post what ```authToken``` and ```decodedAuthToken``` are when you debug, as that might give you some more insight.

Comment: No permission issues with files... However I can't debug the api because it keeps telling me I'm unauthorized. Do I need to send credentials in the url?

Comment: Yes, use PostMan...real easy to add Headers and authorization.  Also added one little addition to my code.  But honestly, what you've done is basically how I've implemented basic authorization a dozen times.